# Paypal Standard - Recurring Payments Giving Error

Tags: php, paypal

When I enter PayPal ID and password on `paypal.com` it says:

> The link you have used to enter the PayPal system is invalid. Please review the link and try again

I am using following HTML code to send it to PayPal:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="_xclick" id="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='AUD'>
<input type='hidden' name='no_note' value='1'>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="abc@gmail.com">
<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value="http://abc.com/cancelprocessing.php">
<input type='hidden' name='return' value="http://abc.com/cpayment_success.php?paymentid=151">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://abc.com/ipn1.php">
<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value="http://abc.com/paypal_cancel.php?paymentid=151">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Plan Details : 52 Week Special ">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="9.95">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="W">
<!--Here comes new recuring payment parameters comes-->
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
</form>
```

**What can be wrong here?**

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="abc@gmail.com">
```

abc@gmail.com is not a valid account, so it will fail.
If you replace this with an existing account it'll work.

(On another note, it won't break it -- now at least, but you may want to remove 'upload'. That's not an applicable parameter for subscriptions, as shown [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HI00JQU).)

Comment: I would think that `abc@gmail.com` is just a simple replacement so that OP need not release his/her personal email, as he/she has done the same for link values.

Comment: I'd think so as well, but after replacing it with a correct (registered) address, his code works. Without one, it fails with the exact same error. ;-)